# How to plot automatically thorugh a list of genes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot 3 line graphs that show the average expression profiles of genes "A", "B" and "C" at stages P0, P1, P2 and 3 corresponding graphs for the percentage of cells that express that gene, given a list of genes_of_interest <- c("A", "B", "c") using the following function:

```
plot_gene_expression <- function(genes, avg_expression_data) {
  for (gene in genes) {
    avg_plot <- ggplot(avg_expression_data, aes(x = stage, y = !!sym(gene))) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(title = paste(gene, "Average Expression"),
           x = "Stage", y = "Expression level") +
      theme_minimal()
    
    pct_plot <- ggplot(percentage_expression_data, aes(x = stage, y = !!sym(gene))) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(title = paste(gene, "Percentage Expression"),
           x = "Stage", y = "Percentage") +
      theme_minimal()
    
    print(cowplot::plot_grid(avg_plot, pct_plot, nrow = 1))
  }
}  


genes_of_interest <- c("A", "B", "c")

plot_gene_expression(genes_of_interest, avg_expression_data, percentage_expression_data, subcluster)
```

The input data is in the following format:

```
avg_expression_data <- data.frame(
  gene = c("A", "B", "c", "D", "E"),
  P0 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  P1 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  P2 = c(11,12,13,14,15)
)

percentage_expression_data <- data.frame(
  gene = c("A", "B", "c", "D", "E"),
  P0 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  P1 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  P2 = c(11,12,13,14,15)
)
```

But I get the error:
`Error in` geom_line()`: ! Problem while computing aesthetics. ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer. Caused by error: ! object 'A' not found`

Do I have to subset the data frames to contain only data for a single gene and iterate through that instead?

Comment: To make your code work you have to reshape (or transpose) your data, e.g. something like `percentage_expression_data |>  tidyr::pivot_longer(-gene, names_to = "stage") |> tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "gene", values_from = "value")
`.